# Sonar Runner unable to publish to Sonarqube via Teamcity

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I'm relatively new to both TeamCity and Sonar so forgive me for any confusion :)

Our TeamCity build is using Sonar Runner (v2.4) to perform an analysis on a C# project, however is failing to publish this to Sonarqube (v5.0.1).

I have tried removing all plugins for Sonarqube to see where the problem lies, however receive the same error with only the C# plugin (v3.3) installed

The access logs for Sonarqube indicate that the analysis is hitting Sonarqube, while the sonar.log file remains unchanged, even with DEBUG on

I've attached the error from the TeamCity build below

Thanks in advance

```
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] INFO: ----------------------------------------
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] INFO: ----------------------------------------------
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] Total time: 56.323s
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] Final Memory: 20M/653M
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] INFO: ----------------------------------------------
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to publish results: /batch/upload_report?project=***********.CS&snapshot=5613683
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.phases.UpdateStatusJob.uploadReport(UpdateStatusJob.java:69)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.phases.UpdateStatusJob.execute(UpdateStatusJob.java:54)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.updateStatusJob(PhaseExecutor.java:175)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:133)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    ... 9 more
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=411, url=http://****************/batch/upload_report?project=***********.CS&amp;snapshot=5613683]
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:132)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:100)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:92)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:84)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.phases.UpdateStatusJob.uploadReport(UpdateStatusJob.java:67)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    ... 34 more
[16:02:50][Step 2/2] Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download             [http://***************/batch/upload_report?project=**********.CS&amp;snapshot=5613683]. Response code: 411
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:304)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:254)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    at             org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:98)
[16:02:50][Step 2/2]    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 0):

That plugin version is ancient. (8 months:-)) Can you try and updated version?

Comment: Hi Mike,
Just tried running the build with the lastest version C# plugin (5.1) but with no luck. Still the same error